# Problem with earphone jack

Tags: hardware, headphone-jack, earphone

I am really afraid of this, but please help me. I was trying to insert the 3.5 mm jack into the slot, and it just stopped midway. All of a sudden. It didn't happen yesterday. I was afraid if something had gone into it. I tried to shake the phone in order to make it come out with no success. With a little harder push, I succeeded and it went inside and the earphone is working fine, and the phone's loudspeakers too. Is something that's wrong? I am afraid. Its my new Moto G4 Plus, and don't want to replace etc. Please help.

Comment: Does it still work? Is it possible that you just didn't push it in far enough the first time?

Comment: Since you bought it new, have it replaced when it's still hot.

Comment: @S.Mitchell It went in completely for the first time. Just yesterday this thing happened.

Comment: @AndyYan It has been one month now. They won't replacement it.